# Changing variables of elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves

$$y^2=x^3+Ax^2+Bx+C.$$
Change $x\longrightarrow x-A/3$, so that the new equation has the form
$$y^2=x^3+ax+b.$$
Can you show step by step what operations we do in the first equation while obtaining the last equation?

Why did we use the $x\longrightarrow x-A/3$ exchange ?

Comment: In general, if you have a polynomial $x^n+ax^{n-1}+\dots$, the variable change $x\to x-a/n$ will eliminate the $x^{n-1}$ term.

Comment: Sir, Can you give a source where this theorem is explained?

Comment: it is not really much of a theorem, you can simply prove it by expanding.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it inductively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sum of the three roots of $p(x)=x^3+Ax^2+Bx+C$ is $-A.$

If $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are the roots of $p(x)$ then $r_1+\frac A3,r_2+\frac A3,r_3+\frac A3$ are the roots of $q(x)=p\left(x-\frac A3\right),$ so the sum of the roots of $q(x)$ is $0.$

Since $q$ is also a monic cubic polynomial (why?,) this means that $q(x)=x^3+ax+b$ for some $a,b.$